# iOS will CATransaction wait after viewDidDisappear before calling the completion block

Tags: swift

will CATransaction wait after viewDidDisappear before calling the completion block?

```
  CATransaction.begin()
    view_controller.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.call_some_function()
    }
    CATransaction.commit()
```

If the view_controller has a custom viewDidDisappear function, will self.call_some_function() execute after that viewDidDisappear function finishes its execution?

I tried to set breakpoints and it turned out that viewDidDisappear did get executed before the completion block. Not sure if this behavior is always predictable as I wasn't able to find any documentation.

Comment: Did you try and what is your result?

Comment: updated above. Yes it turns out that viewDidLoad gets executed before the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

Try seting the completion block before pop view controller

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    self.call_some_function()
}
view_controller.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
CATransaction.commit()
```

or

```
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    self.call_some_function()
}
CATransaction.begin()
view_controller.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
CATransaction.commit()
```